# Deprecated method, but replacing method requires higher api

Tags: android, deprecated

I wanted to use `view.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)` but this method is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29). It is replaced with `.setBackground(Drawable)`. But my minimum of API 8 can't handle that. It tells me to set the minimum to API 16.

**Is there a way to use a different method, based on the API of the device?**

Something like

```
if(API<16)
{
  view.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)
}
else
{
  view.setBackground(Drawable)
}
```

Or do I really have to change the minimum API to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated but it still works so you could just use it. But if you want to be completely correct you should use something like this

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable()
} else {
    setBackground();
}
```

For this to work you need to set buildTarget api 16 and min build to 7 or something similar.

Comment: In this code...the warning will still be shown, you can use suppress warnings to remove it!

Comment: Actually I need both of these: @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: Yea, I forgot to mention the Lint warnings

Comment: Another way to disable the lint check is to place `//noinspection deprecation` on the line before setBackgroundDrawable()

Comment: @BenClayton I never new about `noinspection`, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
   view.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)
} else {
   view.setBackground(Drawable)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use different methods based on the API versions.

For e.g:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        //Methods for version <8 (FROYO)
} else {
        // Methods for version >=8
}
```

Here set your `targetSDkversion` to any higher versions(for e.g 16 here) and set your `minsdkversion` to lower versions ( API 7).